# Values of array randomly change

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

So I have a text file which has information about basketball players and it looks like this:

```
8
9 5 7 -5 13 -4 11
7 5 -3 12 -5 17 -3
25 7 12 -3 5 -5 7 -5 3
14 5 12 -3 10 -7 8
5 1 -40
33 5 15 -5 9 -3 8
11 5 -12 8 -5 12 -3
13 5 3 -4 25 -5 3
```

First integer in the first line shows how many players are there. In every other line the first integer is the number of the player, the second integer shows how many more integers there are in the line and each of the following integers shows if the player is playing (if the integer is positive) or sitting on the bench (if the number is negative).

I want to read the info to an array of structures which look like this:

```
struct player
{
    int nr;
    int k;
    int bus[];
};
```

I've written a function to do so:

```
void skaitymas(int &n, player mas[])
{
    ifstream duom("U1.txt");
    duom >> n;
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        duom >> mas[i].nr >> mas[i].k;
        for (int f=0; f < mas[i].k; f++) {
            duom >> mas[i].bus[f];
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it the program seems to work, however the arrays of structures save unexpected values. After adding some `cout` commands in random places, I found out that it saves the correct values to the array the first time, first for loop loops, but after some iterations it changes the values of the previous arrays. For example, when `i` in the for loop equals `1` then `mas[1].bus[0]` is saved to be `-3`, as it should be, however after `i` changes to `2`, `mas[1].bus[0]` changes to `25`.

I would appreciate it if you would help me to figure it out, why the numbers in the arrays change to other random numbers from the text file, even if I don't do anything to them.

Comment: Did you allocate the memory for you structures? It doesn't look like it.

Comment: You should check the integrity of that array before manipulating it. C++ tends to flaw in memory management and may drop some of the values or get the pointers wrong.

Comment: How do you initialize `bus` array?

Comment: It looks like you may be writing past the end of the bus[] array, which would cause undefined behavior.

Comment: You never check if opening the file or input actually succeeds, which is the first mistake. Taking possibly faulty values and using them as index into an array is the next. There's only one reason to put a semicolon after a closing brace, btw, it's after a class/struct/union/enum definition.

Comment: If this compiles, your compiler is broken.  `int bus[];` has an incomplete type, and class members can't have incomplete types.  (C11 supports this, but even then, you're not allowed to have arrays of such types.)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'm just learning C++ so a lot of definitions and rules are new to me. I've written this program in Free Pascal in a similar way and it worked fine, but it seems I miss something when I write it in C++. And there are no classes in the program.

Comment: @ViliusVaičiulis There's `player`.  The fact that you declare it using the keyword `struct` doesn't change anything; it's a class.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. Values don't change anymore after I change `int bus[]` to something like  `int bus[50]`. I thought you can leave an array without its size information and C++ would just make as much memory as you need for it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.  The most obvious is
that `int bus[]` declares a variable with an incomplete type,
and it is illegal in C++ to declare a member variable with an
incomplete type.  Unless your compiler is seriously broken, this
shouldn't compile; at the very latest, you should get an error
when you write `mas[i]`, since there is no possible way of doing
pointer arithmetic on a pointer to an incomplete type.  The way
to declare your class is:

```
struct Player
{
    int nr;
    std::vector<int> bus;
};
```

Once you do this, you should be able to compile.  Still, it's
very poor C++ to read in counts of the following elements.  The
correct way of doing this would be to drop the counts in the
file: the number of lines is the number of players, and the
number of integers following the first in the line is the number
of integers following the first in the line.  If you do this,
you end up with something like:

```
std::vector<Player> skaitymas()
{
    std::ifsteram duom( "U1.txt" );
    if ( !duom.is_open() ) {
        //  Some sort of error handling, maybe an exception.
    }
    std::vector<Player> results;
    std::string line;
    while ( std::getline( duom, line ) ) {
        std::istringstream s( line );
        int nr;
        s >> nr;
        if ( !s ) {
            //  Format error...
        }
        results.push_back(Player{ nr });
        while ( s >> nr ) {
            results.back().bus.push_back( nr );
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

Everything is done dynamically (which is very simple in C++).

Comment: Could you explain when a type is incomplete? If I write `int bus[50]` instead of `int bus[]`, does it make it complete?

Comment: @ViliusVaičiulis There are several different cases, depending on the type in question, but the essential ones are: an array without an expression in the `[]`, a class with only a forward declaration (e.g. `class MyClass;`, and `void`.  You can't _define_ anything with an incomplete type; you can only declare it.  (But you can define pointers or references to it.)